Problem with MemoryUsageError during Optuna study for a 3DCNN
I am optimizing some parameters in a 3D CNN for semantic segmentation using Optuna, and i am getting problems with the Memory usage during running some trails. I have run other and not get any problems but now i want do some more, and keep getting the same error. I am using MONAI, PyTorch and Optuna.
This is my code:
# Librerias para el manejo de archivos
import logging
import os
import sys
import tempfile
from glob import glob

#Librerias para operaciones generales
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
from Utilities import * 
#from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter

#MONAI
import monai
from monai.data import create_test_image_3d, list_data_collate, decollate_batch
from monai.inferers import sliding_window_inference
from monai.metrics import DiceMetric
from monai.transforms import (
    Activations,
    EnsureChannelFirstd,
    AsDiscrete,
    Compose,
    LoadImaged,
    RandCropByPosNegLabeld,
    RandRotate90d,
    ScaleIntensityd,
    SaveImage,
)
from monai.visualize import plot_2d_or_3d_image
from monai.engines import get_devices_spec

#Optuna
import optuna
def define_3D_unet(trial):
    kernel = trial.suggest_categorical("kernel_size",[1,3,5])
    drop_out = trial.suggest_float("drop_out",0,0.6)
    #Unet
    MODEL = monai.networks.nets.UNet(
    spatial_dims=3,
    in_channels=1,
    out_channels=1,
    kernel_size=kernel,
    channels=(16,32,64,128,256),
    strides=(2,2,2,2),
    num_res_units=2,
    dropout = drop_out
    )

    return MODEL

def objective(trial):
    device ="cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    #Definimos el pipeline de postprocesamiento
    post_trans = Compose(
        [
            Activations(sigmoid=True),
            AsDiscrete(threshold=0.5)
        ]
    )
    model = define_3D_unet(trial).to(device)

    optimizer_name = trial.suggest_categorical("optimizer",["Adam","RMSprop","Adadelta","Adagrad"])
    batch_size = trial.suggest_categorical("batch_size",[1,2,4])

    optimizer = getattr(torch.optim,optimizer_name)(model.parameters())
    #Función de perdida
    loss_function = monai.losses.DiceLoss(sigmoid=True)
    epochs = 400

    #Definimos la métrica que vamos a utilizar
    dice_metric = DiceMetric(include_background=True, reduction="mean", get_not_nans=False)
    train_loader, val_loader, test_loader = preparar_dataloaders(train_files=train_files,
                                                                            val_files=val_files,
                                                                            test_files=test_files,
                                                                            batch_size_train=batch_size,
                                                                            device=device)
    
        
    val_interval = 2

    train_loss_values = []
    #train_metric_values = list()
    val_metric_values = list()

    for i in range(epochs):
        
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()
        print("-" * 10)
        print(f"epoch {i + 1}/{epochs}")

        model.train()
        epoch_loss=0
        step=0
        for batch_data in train_loader:
            step += 1

            # Separamos los datos de entrenamiento en datos y etiquetas
            inputs, labels = batch_data["img"].to(device),batch_data["seg"].to(device)

            #Zero grad
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            # Forward Pass
            outputs = model(inputs)

            # Computamos la función de perdida
            loss = loss_function(outputs, labels)

            #Backward pass
            loss.backward()

            #Optimizer step
            optimizer.step()

            #Calculamos la perdida de cada epoca y la perdida promedio
            epoch_loss += loss.item()
            epoch_len = 16//train_loader.batch_size
            print(f"{step}/{epoch_len}, train_loss: {loss.item():.4f}")

        epoch_loss/= step
        train_loss_values.append(epoch_loss)
        #train_metric_values.append(dice_metric.aggregate().item())
        print(f"epoch {i + 1} avarage loss: {epoch_loss:.4f}")
        print(f'Memory allocated: {torch.cuda.memory_allocated()}')
        print(f'Memory max allocated:{torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated()}')

        if (i + 1) % val_interval == 0:
            model.eval()
            with torch.no_grad():
                val_images = None
                val_labels = None
                val_outputs = None

                for val_data in val_loader:
                    val_images,val_labels = val_data["img"].to(device), val_data["seg"].to(device)
                    roi_size=(96,96,96)
                    sw_batch_size = 4

                    #Calculamos las predicciones para los datos de validación
                    val_outputs = sliding_window_inference(val_images,roi_size,sw_batch_size,model)
                    val_outputs = [post_trans(i) for i in decollate_batch(val_outputs)]

                    #Calculamos el valor de la métrica
                    dice_metric(y_pred=val_outputs, y=val_labels)

                #Guardamos el valor final de la metrica
                metric = dice_metric.aggregate().item()

                #Guardamos los valores obtenidos en el arreglo
                val_metric_values.append(metric)

                #Reiniciamos el estado de la métrica
                dice_metric.reset()

    dice_metric = DiceMetric(include_background=True,reduction="mean", get_not_nans=False)

    post_trans = Compose(
    [
        Activations(sigmoid=True),
        AsDiscrete(threshold=0.5)
    ]
    )

    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

    model.eval()

    with torch.no_grad():
        for test_data in test_loader:
            test_images, test_labels = test_data["img"].to(device),test_data["seg"].to(device)

            roi_size=(96,96,96)

            sw_batch_size = 4

            test_preds = sliding_window_inference(test_images,roi_size,sw_batch_size,model)

            test_preds = [post_trans(j) for j in decollate_batch(test_preds)]

            test_labels = decollate_batch(test_labels)

            dice_metric(y_pred=test_preds,y=test_labels)
    
    trial.report(dice_metric.aggregate().item(),epochs)

    if trial.should_prune():
        raise optuna.exceptions.TrialPruned()
    
    return dice_metric.aggregate().item()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Imprimimos la configuración para comprobar que este todo bien
    monai.config.print_config()
    logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO)

    data_dir = "./files/data/volume"
    labels_dir = "./files/data/labels/edit"

    train_files, val_files, test_files = dividir_archivos(data_dir, labels_dir)
    #Definimos las keys para simplicidad
    keys = ["img","seg"]

    # Device: setup as cpu for the lab
    device ="cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
    print(f'Device: {device}')
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    print(f'Memory allocated: {torch.cuda.memory_allocated()}')
    print(f'Memory max allocated:{torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated()}')

    study = optuna.load_study(storage="sqlite:///db.sqlite3",
                                study_name="prepration_study_400")
    study.optimize(objective,n_trials = 29,show_progress_bar=True)

    pruned_trials=[t for t in study.trials if t.state==optuna.trial.TrialState.PRUNED]
    complete_trials=[t for t in study.trials if t.state==optuna.trial.TrialState.COMPLETE]

    print("Study statistics: ")
    print(f" Number of finished trials: {len(study.trials)}")
    print(f" Number of prunned trials: {len(pruned_trials)}")
    print(f" Number of complete trials: {len(complete_trials)}")

    print("Best trial:")
    trial = study.best_trial

    print(f" Value: {trial.value}")

    print(f" Params:")
    for key, value in trial.params.items():
        print(f"   {key}: {value}")


This is the Error i get:
html#environment-variables)
[W 2024-05-15 20:29:42,837] Trial 39 failed with value None.                                                                                                                                              
  0%|                                                                                                                                                                              | 0/29 [00:18<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "files/Optuna_training.py", line 218, in <module>
    study.optimize(objective,n_trials = 29,show_progress_bar=True)
  File "/home/notvenja24/anaconda3/envs/training/lib/python3.8/site-packages/optuna/study/study.py", line 451, in optimize
    _optimize(
  File "/home/notvenja24/anaconda3/envs/training/lib/python3.8/site-packages/optuna/study/_optimize.py", line 62, in _optimize
    _optimize_sequential(
  File "/home/notvenja24/anaconda3/envs/training/lib/python3.8/site-packages/optuna/study/_optimize.py", line 159, in _optimize_sequential
    frozen_trial = _run_trial(study, func, catch)
  File "/home/notvenja24/anaconda3/envs/training/lib/python3.8/site-packages/optuna/study/_optimize.py", line 247, in _run_trial
    raise func_err
  File "/home/notvenja24/anaconda3/envs/training/lib/python3.8/site-packages/optuna/study/_optimize.py", line 196, in _run_trial
    value_or_values = func(trial)
  File "files/Optuna_training.py", line 116, in objective
    loss.backward()
  File "/home/notvenja24/anaconda3/envs/training/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 513, in backward
    return handle_torch_function(
  File "/home/notvenja24/anaconda3/envs/training/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/overrides.py", line 1621, in handle_torch_function
    result = torch_func_method(public_api, types, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/notvenja24/anaconda3/envs/training/lib/python3.8/site-packages/monai/data/meta_tensor.py", line 282, in __torch_function__
    ret = super().__torch_function__(func, types, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/notvenja24/anaconda3/envs/training/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 1418, in __torch_function__
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/notvenja24/anaconda3/envs/training/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 522, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(
  File "/home/notvenja24/anaconda3/envs/training/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 266, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 216.00 MiB. GPU 0 has a total capacity of 3.82 GiB of which 209.50 MiB is free. Including non-PyTorch memory, this process has 3.57 GiB memory in use. Of the allocated memory 2.34 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 295.47 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF=expandable_segments:True to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management  (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#environment-variables)

Please somebody help i don't know what to do anymore.
I have tried deleting and cleaning the cache and the wasted of the GPU memory with torch.cuda.empty_cache but i keep getting problems.
Maybe there is another method for keep doing my Study so don't have to start over with other configuration of the net and more parameters.

This is 4 months old, but since no answers, I'll give it a try. I had similar issue with optuna, and it was caused by training batch_size being too big. The problem is that, as you know, optuna chooses batch_size according to its' search algorithm. So, depending on the chosen value, some trials may succeed and others may throw OOM (if the chosen batch_size requires too much GPU RAM), which seems to match your symptoms.
In my situation, the max. batch_size was 128. Reducing it to 64 reduced max. memory usage and solved the issue.
In your case, I notice the max. batch_size is 4, which isn't that big. Nevertheless, I would try reducing it to 2, to find out if this solves the OOM issue.
If that doesn't help, I would print GPU memory usage in the forward pass using the pynvml package. That is how I diagnosed my problem.
